# C# Asp.net MVC - how do i properly pass data pulled from an external API to display on the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to using ASP.NET and the MVC method. I was hoping to get advice regarding what went wrong with my code.
Currently, i'm trying to pull data from an API and showing it in a browser view.

This is the API JSON Data that i'm trying to get:

```
{
"value": [
    {
      "BusStopCode": "01012",
      "RoadName": "Victoria St",
      "Description": "Hotel Grand Pacific",
      "Latitude": 1.29684825487647,
      "Longitude": 103.85253591654006
    },
    {
      "BusStopCode": "01013",
      "RoadName": "Victoria St",
      "Description": "St. Joseph's Ch",
      "Latitude": 1.29770970610083,
      "Longitude": 103.8532247463225
    },
    {
      "BusStopCode": "01019",
      "RoadName": "Victoria St",
      "Description": "Bras Basah Cplx",
      "Latitude": 1.29698951191332,
      "Longitude": 103.85302201172507
    },
    // and the list goes on and on...
]}
```

Below are my MVC classes:

1. Model Class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SGTrafficAnalytics.Models
{

    public class BusStopsModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string BusStopCode { get; set; }
        public string RoadName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
    }

}
```

2. View Class .cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel>

        @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
            foreach (var v in i.value)
            {
                <div>@v.BusStopCode</div>
            }
        }
```

3. Controller class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SGTrafficAnalytics.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SGTrafficAnalytics.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static string API_KEY = "xxx";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            var URL = new UriBuilder("http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusStops");
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("AccountKey", API_KEY);
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var content = client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

            //List<Value> valueList = new List<Value>();
            var valueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusStopsModel>(content);

            return View(valueList);
        }        
    }
}
```

First, i want to know as my model contains a class called BusStopsModel which has a List containing all the information that i need, is my code for deserializing correct? `var valueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusStopsModel>(content);` Online searches mostly leads me to solutions excluding a List in the model class.

Second, upon running, i'll get an error saying the view dictionary requires an IEnumerable type. But i found out that you can't deserialize the object into a List type. How do i resolve this issue?

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel', but this dictionary 
requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel]'.
```

Third, since i have a List, is it correct to have 2 foreach in the view class to access the inner data? Also, is it correct to to put `@model IEnumerable<SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel>`?

Fourth, is using WebClient to get the API acceptable? i've seen other methods such as REST or WebAPI but they are mostly used for local data and not external data? i've also heard about jQuery and ajax but not sure how to use them. Also, HTTPClient has async, meaning its more faster and efficient compared to WebClient?

Greatly appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deserializing a single instance of your model:

```
var valueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusStopsModel>(content);
```

But the view is expecting a collection of that model:

```
@model IEnumerable<SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel>
```

Basically, an apple is not a basket of apples.  From the data and model structure, it looks like the single instance is likely correct.  (You can observe the deserialization results in your debugger to confirm if this is the case.)  Update the view to expect the model you want to pass to it:

```
@model SGTrafficAnalytics.Models.BusStopsModel
```

And in the view it looks like you want to loop through the model's `.value` property, not the model itself:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.value)
```

Overall it looks like you're just getting confused about the semantics.  You have a model which contains a list.  The model *itself* isn't a list.

Comment: thank you! but may i ask whether should my webclient be located in an async method? or is it fine currently?

Comment: @UVERtainment: The method should only be `async` if it's performing an awaitable operation.  If there is an `async` version of any of the methods you're calling then you can certainly switch to those and make your controller action itself `async`.  It's not necessary, simply an option available to you.